# Change display settings via keyboard (display 1 only, display 2 only, display 1 + 2, repeat)

Tags: 16.04, display, settings

This is something I got pretty used to coming from a windows laptop. Is this available somehow in Ubuntu 16.04 (desktop, not laptop). I am running with an AMD/ATI brand card using the built in drivers.

Comment: Don't you want to add "Mirror" and "Extended Desktop" options in your question too?

Comment: I think this is generally implemented in hardware in those laptops, and then the system has to deal with the removing/adding of those displays as they get (dis)connected by the BIOS.